# Notepad++ v8.x search results clearing previous search

Tags: notepad++

Older versions of NP++ was keeping the search results until cleared or application restarted. After upgrading v7.x to v8.2 I observe that this now does not work anymore. I could guess this has moved to checkbox but I can't find it to enable this feature.

How to restore the multiple search results in NP++?

Comment: I really find annoying that NP++ developers do not fallow simple principle: keep behavior same as before, so by default it should be false instead true. This is not occurrence with NP++ when behavior gets changed silently and finding out takes a huge time read and finally ask questions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Search something
- On the search window right-click to open a option window.
- un-check `Purge for every search`

[image]